# How do you connect MarkLogic to Tableau (Mac OS)?

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, marklogic

I'm trying to connect MarkLogic to Tableau through an ODBC (to connect Tableau with MarkLogic) on my Mac. While Tableau does have an ODBC driver available to download @ https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers, it "is not supported on the selected operating system."

I have considered downloading a Windows Virtual Machine on my Mac as last resort since it works for that. However is there a way to get an ODBC working on the Mac OS?

Comment: I've found that using a Virtual Machine is not a bad way to go, however there is a problem with the ML9-compatible ODBC driver and Windows 32bit. The Windows 64bit driver works fine. Engineering is looking into it. The ML8 driver works fine with both 32 and 64 bit. If you want the ML9 features and are using Windows, make sure it's 64-bit. I haven't tried a Linux VM...

Comment: I've actually just started running into this problem. Thank you so much for this insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MarkLogic's ODBC connector is only for Linux and Windows: http://developer.marklogic.com/products/odbc. You'll need one of those OSs.